# Sql Developer conditions from Excel

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have around 15.000 conditions in excel. And I want to read this condition and write into "where in" clause on sql developer.
Is it possible?

Comment: What kind of conditions? Can you bring some example? What kind of data do you have?

Comment: select * from table where login in('user1','user2','user3',...) query will be like this. I need to run query with too many username . And all username must read excel or textfile. Because sql developer has 1000 line limit.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can easily import the usernames from excel file into Oracle table. Assuming the Oracle table `temp` has the column `logins` where 1500 records stored in it, then you can build your query as follows:

```
SELECT *   
FROM temp  
WHERE logins IN ('user1', 'user2', ...., 'user1000')  
OR logins IN ('user1001', 'user1002', ...., 'user2000')   
OR ....  
OR logins IN ('user14001', 'user14002', ...., 'user15000');
```

I know this is not efficient as might need. But I cannot recall any other method. There are some tools you can use to convert all these 15K values in OR options (put them in single quotes with comma).